# Why does a typed dataset cause an insert rather than an update (causing primary key violation)?

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm trying to use a dataset to update some rows in a database, simple.

I'm creating a typed dataset instance, disabling constraints, adding a few rows to one table and populating a few of the columns in the rows, including the primary key, with existing and correct primary key values. Yet, when I call update on the data adapter it's throwing a `primary key violation`.

I'm not providing values for every column, only those I want to update. Why does the adapter not recognise an update is required?

```
MyDataset dataSet = new MyDataset();
dataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
```

Comment: Are you loading the data you're ultimately updating from the datastore you're updating, or creating new rows locally that also exist in the datastore?

Comment: Red flag: disabling constraints. Are there any constraints in the database that would get violated in such an update?

Comment: overslacked - the second option, just creating new rows with data that was passed from a business layer.

Comment: Oded - I understand the implications of disabling constraints, thanks. I have no choice in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because you **Add()** the records... That marks them as *new* and they will trigger an Insert statement on update.

Comment: If you must Add() the records, then also call AcceptChanges() on the dataset. That will mark them as Unchanged. But be sure the primary key is correct, otherwise you'll be at risk to update the wrong record when the records do eventually change and you try to save them.

Comment: Is there any option other than retrieving the row from the database before updating it and saving back? This seems like an entirely unnecessary round trip. I pulled the PK in an earlier select, I really don't want to have to do that again, nor do I want to keep a dataset hanging around in memory. (This is a legacy app and I'm abstracting the datasets/dataadapters from the business layer).

Comment: @malcom Could you switch to Ado Edntity Fx? That allows full control.

Comment: Henk - no, I have no choice but to work with this as is, its legacy unfortunately. So am I right in thinking that when I want my business layer to trigger an update, I have to repopulate the dataset from the database and update the rows rather than add them to a new dataset instance?

Comment: @malcom that would be the safest. But note that a trick was suggested by Charlie: Add(), AcceptChanges(), change a property, Update()